# TestNG reports email after test executions

Tags: testng

I've found various links for sending TestNG reports to be emailed after test executions here are two of the links

https://loganathan1988.wordpress.com/2014/11/03/how-to-email-automated-test-execution-reports-as-an-attachment-using-java-mail-api-in-selenium/comment-page-1/#comment-9 http://www.assertselenium.com/java/emailable-reports-for-selenium-scripts/

I've downloaded mail.jar as well but don't know how to configure all this with my project to send an email after test execution

Comment: create new method , Add code which send mail and run it. But I think you will get issue that Testng sending previous run test mail always. So better you use Jenkins for mail.

Comment: DO you use any form of CI tool like Jenkins or bamboo?  I would tend to advise against adding functionality to your program when most reporting systems include the functionality already.

Answer (score 1):

You can try on below link. Hope it will help you to configure in your project.

https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/send-reports-automatically-to-email-using-maven-from-eclipse/